# Pyplot lemniscate

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

i wonder if someone knows a more elegant way to plot a lemnicate in python (in terms of formula or other nice ideas are welcome). I fetched the formula from wikipedia. But wonder if it is possible to shorten the formular or so to make it more nice looking.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
alpha = 1

#plot a lemniskate

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num=1000) # 10^3 points 

x = [alpha * np.sqrt(2)*np.cos(i) / (np.sin(i)**2+1) for i in t]

y = [alpha * np.sqrt(2)*np.cos(i)*np.sin(i) / (np.sin(i)**2+1) for i in t]

plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy arrays support "vectorized" operations. They're much faster and more memory-efficient than iterating through the array and creating a list from it.

Therefore, there's no need for the list comprehension in this case. It's better to operate on `t` directly.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = 1
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num=1000)

x = alpha * np.sqrt(2) * np.cos(t) / (np.sin(t)**2 + 1)
y = alpha * np.sqrt(2) * np.cos(t) * np.sin(t) / (np.sin(t)**2 + 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Also, if you only want the shape, and don't care about the absolute values, you can omit the constants:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num=1000)

x = np.cos(t) / (np.sin(t)**2 + 1)
y = np.cos(t) * np.sin(t) / (np.sin(t)**2 + 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]